# how to write an artificial request

Tags: post

how can i construct a artificial request to login to twitter or any site for that matter that accpets post forms.
what i've been trying is to extract the headers and post request parameters from the origional request(directed at the action atribute  of the form) and copy it to the outgoing url object that i am making.but it just won't work.

And i am aware of the apis and i don't wanna use them i am trying this to write a web proxy site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question (e.g. "aware of the APIs and I don't want to use them") but [urlib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) may be useful, particularly `urllib.FancyURLopener(...)`.

Comment: i meant i don't want to use the twitter api for the same .

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) ?

It's a library that allows you to interact with servers using a bunch of different protocoles, including HTTP. So, for instance, you can simulate POST or GET request.

You can use it as a command line tool or as a library from many languages (PHP, C, etc ...)